# Is it possible to rename repositories in Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory

We'd like to introduce a naming convention as we have a large number of both internal and external repositories and thus we'd like to make it obvious what's what. At the time these repositories were added, nobody expected things to grow this much.

I was wondering if it would be possible to rename the repositories? I know I can create new ones and copy/move the artifacts there, but that looks like a bigger effort than I'd like. Is there a reasonable way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No and yes. You shouldn't, but you can. I guess you can imagine why you shouldn't, and for all those reasons the name is not editable in the UI.

You can edit the names in the settings.xml (in the UI under Admin->Advanced, by REST) or as a file, bootsraping Artifactory with it). All three ways are described [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuration+Files).

Note that you do it on your own risk.

---

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) and [[artifactory]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>

Comment: I was thinking of changing the name via the xml file as well, but I wasn't sure if that was sufficient. From the link you gave me, that doesn't become clear either.

Comment: As I mention, we officially don't recommend to do it, so you won't find it documented in any place in our documentation.

Comment: I asked if it's enough, because I tried it the other day and in the UI, after a change to xml and a restart of Artifactory, I still see the of id of the repository. I understand it's not supported, just wanted to see what the options are.

Comment: Following @JBaruch hints, I was able to "rename" a repository with artifactory 4.7.1; the change was effective *immediately without needing to restart the service*.

Comment: Changing the name of an artifactory file makes sense when you have just uploaded it if you made some typo.

Answer (score 2):

You can right click on the repo or file and select --> "Move" then select "target repository" and select "custom target path" and write the new name.

Answer (score 0):

As the JFrog said, It is better to create a repository with a new name and then move contents from the old repository into the new repository.